# How can I copy data from another App Kintone?

Tags: javascript

My requirement is to -

1. `Create` an app with a button
2. On button click, `show data` of source App.

My solution is *GET data* from *source App* and *POST* it to *main App*.
But I'm unable to update my main App because of which I'm finding trouble moving forward.

`Note: I must use JS customize.`

My code is below:

```js
let copyId = 112;
let appID = kintone.app.getId();
function getCopyAppData() {
    let body = {
      "app": copyId,
      "query": kintone.app.getQuery()
    };
    return kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'GET', body).then(function(resp) {return resp;})

      
 }
  function addDataToCurrentApp(data) {
    let body = {
      "app": appID,
      "records": data
    };
    return kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'POST', body).then(function(resp) {
      return resp;
    })
  }
getCopyAppData().then(function(data) {
  let events = ['app.record.create.show', 'app.record.edit.show', "app.record.index.show"];
    kintone.events.on(events, function(e) {
      if (document.getElementById('addData') !== null) {
          return;
      }
      let menuButton = document.createElement("button");
          menuButton.id = "addData";
          menuButton.innerHTML = "Add data";
      kintone.app.getHeaderMenuSpaceElement().appendChild(menuButton);
      menuButton.onclick = function() {
        addDataToCurrentApp(data);
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the previous comment was deleted so lemme answer your question again.

This is an example code of copying data from another app in Kintone.

```
(function() {
"use strict";
let copyId = 112;
let appID = kintone.app.getId();
function getCopyAppData() {
    let body = {
      "app": copyId,
      "query": kintone.app.getQuery()
    };
    // return kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'GET', body).then(function(resp) {return resp;})
    return kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'GET', body).then(function(resp) {
        addDataToCurrentApp(resp.records); 
        return resp
    })


 }
  function addDataToCurrentApp(data) {


    var wData = [];
    for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){
        var param2 = {
                      "str":{
                         "value":data[i].str.value
                    }
                }
        wData.push(param2);
    }

//        wData.push(data[i]);



    let body = {
      "app": appID,
      "records":wData
    };

    return kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'POST', body).then(function(resp) {
      return resp;
    },function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
  }
// getCopyAppData().then(function(data) {
  let events = ['app.record.create.show', 'app.record.edit.show', "app.record.index.show"];
    kintone.events.on(events, function(e) {
      if (document.getElementById('addData') !== null) {
          return;
      }
      let menuButton = document.createElement("button");
          menuButton.id = "addData";
          menuButton.innerHTML = "Add data";
      kintone.app.getHeaderMenuSpaceElement().appendChild(menuButton);
      menuButton.onclick = function() {
        // addDataToCurrentApp(data);
        getCopyAppData();
          }
        })
    // })     
})();
```

FYI, in a similar case, I've seen a user got stuck in the error code GAIA_DA02.
This is due to too many processes running at the same time.

In this case, please consider the following to help you avoid the same kind of error.

•Reduce the number of fields and registered records in each app so that it doesn't take too long to process such as record updates. 

•Split API requests and avoid duplication of processing time 

•Simplify your app settings, such as setting permissions, with complex settings, etc.

•Records that could not be updated with an error should be left for retry processing, and then retry at a time when other update processing and time do not overlap.

Also, there's a similar inquiry at the Kintone developer community site so please look at it for your reference.
https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/community/posts/360027677873-Copy-data-from-another-app

I hope this helps